# Reset to default table sales_order_status

Tags: magento-2.1, database, sales-order, order-status

I need to reset 2 tables to default content:

1. sales_order_status
2. sales_order_status_state

Payment modules installed:

1. MercadoPago
2. PagSeguro

I installed these payment module and they modified the original value of the tables in field that cant change the status value.

A print with actual content:

[image]

Which command can I run on mysql to accomplish this (default content of tables?) ?

My magento version: 2.1.6.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to import both table again by installing MAGENTO 2.1.6 in local machine.First export both table from newly installed magento then go to DB from which your website is running,delete both corrupted table then import newly table.As I am guessing there is not any command to reset table.
Keep backup of DB before doing this.

Also if you got any command to do this,please let me know.